# Equivalence between Deconvolution and the Gradient of the Convolution wrt to its input - Convnets

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

first of all I'm not sure if I should post this here or in the computer science forum so correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

I understand that a deconvolution (transposed convolution) can be viewed as a matrix operation like so:

```
Let O: output of the convolution
    I: input
    K: kernel
```

Where we unrolled the input and output has vectors and transformed the kernel
    matrix adequately.

Then the deconvolution is given by multiplying the output of the convolution by the transpose of the kernel matrix:

```
O * K_transpose = I
```

But how is this equivalent to the gradient of O with respect to I?